# Nested NULLIF with ISDATE to eliminate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017, nullif

I have a column (datatype `nvarchar(max)`, not my choice, legacy) with various different uses to the end user dependent on other factors.

I was trying to narrow down to certain specific data within that column given earlier clauses within some sample (but highly representative) data I noticed that the remaining data was either a 1,2,3,4, or a date

I initially added some nested `NULLIF` along with an `IS NOT NULL`

```
AND NULLIF(NULLIF(NULLIF(NULLIF([ColumnName],'1'),'2'),'3'),'4') IS NOT NULL
```

The 1 is as a string because in the global data there are some strings so removing the single brackets creates an implied conversion to int which many records would fail. This got me down to 25 records in my sample, the records with dates and the target records

I then thought I'd add an `ISDATE` to isolate those records

```
AND NULLIF(NULLIF(NULLIF(NULLIF(ISDATE([ColumnName]),'1'),'2'),'3'),'4') IS NOT NULL
```

This then returned 60k or so records, which was not the behaviour I expected.

I ran the following queries to see if there was any incompatibility with the two commands inline but the returned as expected

```
SELECT NULLIF(ISDATE('06/01/2022'),1)
```

returned `NULL`.

```
SELECT NULLIF(ISDATE('06/01/2022'),'1')
```

in case it didn't like a string, but returned `NULL`.

```
SELECT NULLIF(NULLIF(ISDATE('06/01/2022'),'1'),'2')
```

in case it didn't like the nest, but returned `NULL`.

So why does it not NULL the values that present as dates, and also why does it negate the other NULLIF commands in the outer parts of the nest?

Comment: `ISDATE` is a bad function you should not use, as it offers no way to specify the formats you want to accept (and not all date types accept all formats). Use `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_PARSE` instead. Both return `NULL` on failure, which is easy to combine with `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`.

Comment: For the test I'd suggest `([Column] IN ('1','2','3','4') OR TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [Column]) IS NOT NULL)` (add third parameter to control the format as necessary) rather than chaining `NULLIF`.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I'll look into that as some slipped through the net, that's why I deleted my answer in the hope that someone else might make better more elegant suggestions

Comment: `ISDATE` asks if a string is a date and only returns 1 or 0, so you'd want it around your `NULLIF` not inside it. And it's a terrible function, you should probably use `TRY_CONVERT` as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm an idiot

I forgot to catch all the times that the `ISDATE()` returned a 0, so it was returning all the values that the `NULLIF`s were trying to catch

```
AND ISDATE(ISNULL(NULLIF(NULLIF(NULLIF(NULLIF([2nd Ref],'1'),'2'),'3'),'4'),'06/01/2022')) = 0
```

So changing the order here helped, creating `NULL`s for the expected values, changing those into a known date, then returning where it isn't a date

That should now work as expected. Oh well, someone might one day find it useful

edit: There are a couple of records that still have dates in them, I will also use the `TRYCONVERT` as Jeroen suggested